# How can I go back to the editing file after invoking shell in Ex mode?

Tags: ex-mode

I run into a problem while practicing the Ex mode by running `sh` command, following this [tutorial](https://kb.iu.edu/d/afdc). I cannot go back to the editing file[s].

1. I can see the .swp dot file by running `ls -a`.
2. None listed by running `jobs`
3. `fg` can neither call it back.

I cannot find a relavant question here, except this [one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4817/is-there-a-vim-command-line-option-to-edit-last-edited-file), but absolutely it cannot tackle this problem. Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type `exit` at the prompt and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to terminate the current shell session and come back to Vim and your previous session.

`$ jobs` and `$ fg` don't work because you don't have background jobs *in the current shell session*. Those commands would work if you used `<C-z>` instead of `:sh`, though.

`:sh` suspends the current shell session and starts a new one in which you can't access processes running or suspended in the previous one. The only way to get back the previous session is to terminate the current one.

`<C-z>` only suspends Vim. This puts you back in the shell where you started Vim and where you can see Vim with `$ jobs` and switch back to it with `$ fg`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that typing `Ctrl+C` would go back to command input and then typing `visual` should bring you back to normal editing the document.

Comment: I think you are confusing the command line window (opened with `q:`) and the `:sh` command which opens a new shell session.